# Why I get a syntax error when using typedef in verilog?

Tags: typedef, verilog

I don not know what is wrong here. I use a modelsim SE 6.5b. Then when I use "typedef" I get a syntax error.

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

    // Type define a struct
    typedef struct {
      byte a;
      reg  b;
      shortint unsigned c;
    } myStruct;

    module typedef_data ();

    // Full typedef here
    typedef integer myinteger;

    // Typedef declaration without type
    typedef myinteger;
    // Typedef used here
    myinteger a = 10;
    myStruct object = '{10,0,100};

    initial begin
      $display ("a = %d", a);
      $display ("Displaying object");
      $display ("a = %b b = %b c = %h", object.a, object.b, object.c);
      #1 $finish;
    end
```

Comment: Please show the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` is a SystemVerilog keyword, not Verilog.

To enable SystemVerilog on Modelsim you need to add the `-sv` compile option and/or rename the file to with a `.sv` extension.

Comment: I recommend using a *.sv file extension on files that contain SystemVerilog instead of using the -sv switch, which is global.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on Modelsim 10.1d.  See example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/cn) (I had to add an `endmodule` but it's otherwise unmodified).

I'd suggest checking your compile flags to ensure you're enabling support for SystemVerilog during compilation.